# 401 error when using docker push to private registry (Heroku Registry)

Tags: docker, heroku, unauthorized

While following [Heroku's docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#building-and-pushing-image-s) for how to push a docker image to their registry, I keep running into this error:

```sh
> docker push registry.heroku.com/<MY-APP>/web                                                                                                cd
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/<MY-APP>/web]
e0d052f1dc62: Preparing 
41ec0e96eb83: Preparing 
d081ada49467: Waiting 
73c3e7ef7bc6: Waiting 
unauthorized: authentication required
```

I continue to get a `Login Succeeded` whenever I try to use `docker login`, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

I tried to debug using the Docker Daemon logs but those weren't helpful.

Comment: After hours of struggle I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76695342/5465632) and have added here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was bitten by what I'd consider to be a bug with the Heroku registry that stems from a debate about how to deny the user properly when they're logged in but try to access a resource that either doesn't exist or isn't theirs so that sensitive info, like the existence of a resource, isn't exposed (check [this summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039015/3739332) if you're interested).

**TL;DR** - Heroku *shuold* be sending a 404 but send a 401 instead - Go make the app via the UI and then try again.

Comment: May god bless you because I was about to try some nonesensical stuff

Comment: @jose-v Hey, the fact that one person found this helpful means it was worth posting! Cheers!