# Best practice to identify it is no value or no permission in json

Tags: json, rest

API return data in json format
response:
{
name : 'John'
creditCardNum: '123456789'
}

What's the best practice to identify the creditCardNum has no value (maybe not yet setup the credit card) or the request user has no permission to view credit card info?

I am thinking of : 
**No Value :**
{
name : 'John'
}
**No permission :** 
{
name : 'John'
noPermissionCreditCardNum : true
}

But for no permission, I need to add another field for identify it is no permission.

Comment: Why not just check if the `creditCardNum` property has a value or not?

Comment: Return HTTP status 200 (OK) with message body containing all data when user has permissions. Return 403 (Forbidden) when user is now allowed to access resource (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547474/correct-http-status-code-when-resource-is-available-but-not-accessible-because-o) with specific error message.

Comment: I need to show different messages for No-Value and No-permission.

Comment: I cant just return 403 for whole of json data, because only creditCardNum has permission issue.